# Language- or msbuild-supported default usings for c# classes

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Is it possible to include "default" `using` statements for all c# classes in a project? ASP.NET Razor has this feature, so I wonder whether it's possible in c# itself.

I'm not asking about templates, tools, vs/vscode, code weaving / fody, etc.

Maybe it's possible to do this in msbuild in a `Directory.Build.props`?

If impossible, is there a technical reason/limitation why the language or msbuild cannot support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not currently possible. But it will be in c# 10 and the feature is called Global Usings https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2021/05/c-100-introducing-global-usings.html

which is due in November 2021